# Issue with shadow_mark() in gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I've created a gif using gganimate that shows NBA players regular season points per game and compares it to their points per game in the playoffs.  I have everything working except i have a graphical issue with `shadow_mark()`.  The gif starts at the playoffs, transitions to the regular season mark, and then transitions back to playoffs mark.

I want `shadow_mark()` to keep the playoffs mark on the graph at all times with 50% opacity like i have it right now.  I don't want the regular season mark to stay on the graph, but I don't know how to get rid of it.  I've tried various combinations of `past = TRUE` and `future = FALSE` etc in `shadow_mark()` but it doesn't seem to have solved it.  I've also tried `exclude_layer = 1` but then that deletes both of the shadows instead of just the 1.

[image]

Here is my gif as of right now.  Below is the code used to create it.

```
j <- ggplot(nba2, aes(x = PPG, y = Player)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, stroke = 1, aes(fill = Tm, size = 2)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = 'none') +
  xlab("Points Per Game") +
  labs(caption = 'Data via basketball-reference.com')
plot(j)
anim <- j +
  transition_states(Playoff_or_reg,
                    transition_length = 2,
                    state_length = 2, 
                    wrap = TRUE) +
  shadow_mark(past = TRUE, future = FALSE, alpha = 0.5) +
ggtitle("{closest_state}")
anim
```

Any help on how to fix this issue would be appreciated!

Comment: can you share where did you get the data? the one that I get from here https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2017_totals.html does not playoffs separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wanna do is create a new variable that equals each player's PPG in the regular season. That variable is going to be your static, transparent point. The original variable is the one that is going to transition.

Here's what the code for that viz might look like:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Player, y = PPG, color = Tm, fill = Tm)) + 
  geom_point(size = 4.5, shape = 21, alpha = 1, stroke = 1) + 
  geom_point(size = 4.5, shape = 21, alpha = .2,  stroke = 1,  aes(fill = Tm, color = Tm, x = Player, y = newPPG)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  transition_states(
    Playoff_or_reg,
    transition_length = 1,
    state_length = 2)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I see your work all the time on the nba reddit !  I can't believe you answered lol but yes this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you I appreciate it !

Comment: Right on. Happy to help